# "lining up" or "lined up"

Tags: phrases

> It's hard to imagine now those big crowds ***lining up*** in the frigid cold eager for the change to work in a bustling factory for $5 a day.

I usually see *line up* used like this: somebody *line* somebody *up*,such as follows:

> He lined us all up in the corridor.
>
> The windows should be lined up with the door frame.

So I think, is it more appropriate to use the passive: to change ***lining up*** to ***lined up***? Because *those big crowds* ***are*** *lined up* ***by*** somebody. Which is right? Thanks.

Comment: That's probably because it is **now** lining up... This could have been 'It's hard to imagine that those big crowds **lined up** in the frigid cold...."

Comment: I usually think of a *crowd* as a group of people, or those people themselves, so I would say *The crowd **lined** themselves **up**.* Thus, *It's hard to imagine now those big crowds **lining up** ...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrasal verb *line up* can be used transitively, as described in the question. However, it can also be used intransitively, meaning to form a line/stand in a queue. The usage in the example in question is standard.

[Some examples from COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=28145691):

> – Relatives and friends **lined up** outside the building to find out of their loved ones.
>   – The Metropolitan Museum of Art in New York had crowds **lining up** for the Alexander McQueen exhibit
>   – he'll grouse about not getting any respect and being an outsider while everybody is **lining up** to kiss his ring.
>   – Spectators had begun **lining up** outside before midnight for seats in the public section
>   – In the evening, the kids were **lining up** washing their hands to eat dinner
>   – In some places, people are still **lining up** for aid, indicating a certain resistance to Taliban strictures
>   – planes must **line up** for a chance to pass through the narrow military-authorized corridors
>   – The minute the sun starts setting, the girls **line up** like little soldiers and march themselves to bed
>   – Everyone will **line up** for miles to see a dinosaur.
>   – Here the Klan **lines up** for a group picture.
>   – He likes the bus and its big noise even if he has to wait while kids call and yell and everyone **lines up** and he's the only one the driver carries up the steps.